# How to disable default publishing interval time i.e. every 3 seconds on AWS IoT

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-iot

I am new to AWS IoT. I am using "AWSIotDevice" as super class of my virtual device.
By using below, i am able to update shadow on AWS IoT. But my concern is, it is updating shadow every 3 seconds. I don't require it. Shadow should update only after setting new values in my virtual device. It can be after 10 seconds or 30 seconds. I tried using "setKeepAliveInterval" to 30 seconds, but still it is updating shadow every 3 seconds.

Please suggest how to disable it or increase the interval for longer time say 10 minutes or so?

```
AWSIotMqttClient awsIotClient = new AWSIotMqttClient(clientEndpoint,
             clientId, pair.keyStore, pair.keyPassword);
awsIotClient.setKeepAliveInterval(30000);
AWSIotDevice awsIotDevice = new MyAWSIotDevice(thingName);
awsIotClient.attach(awsIotDevice);
awsIotClient.connect(10000);
```

Really appreciate your help.

Regards,
Krishan

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explicitly said, but that looks like the Java SDK.

That being the case, you need to change the [DEVICE_REPORT_INTERVAL](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/blob/f857d88ec1a8035f1778d0b73b23c9eea82f270e/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/iot/client/AWSIotConfig.java#L83), which, as you've notice, defaults to `3000ms`.

To do this on `AWSIotDevice` you should use [setReportInterval](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/blob/5d9830bb21d167eea995dcad38e77ad6835adc7e/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/iot/client/AWSIotDevice.java#L139).

Comment: Thanks Thomas,
Yes, you are right. It's Java SDK.
One more question, with setReportInterval() it is behaving unexpected way.

I tried using "awsThing.setReportInterval(5000);".
It is working but it is not working as expected or explained.
E.g. in case of 5000 value, shadow is being updated every 10 second whereas my device was sending message every 5 seconds.
Also, in case of 10000 value (awsThing.setReportInterval(10000);) and device sending message every 5 seconds, i am getting error "Connection temporarily lost" and it is not updating shadow at all.